# how to active menu bar on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on react application.I have create general layout of page which contain sidebar and its working fine and active particular link which is clicked.Now i have created another page which contain button of same nav menu and redirect to specific page which i want.When i clicked on the button the sidebar specific menu is not activated.it activated only when I click on sidebar link.i am using semantic react for this.How can i handle the menu active item for both side.My general layout:

```
 class SidebarLeftOverlay extends Component {
      state = { visible: false,activeItem: 'home' }

      toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
       handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })
      render() {
        const { visible } = this.state
        return (
          <div>
            <Button onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>Toggle Visibility</Button>
            <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
              <Sidebar as={Menu} animation='overlay' width='thin' visible={visible} icon='labeled' vertical>
                 <Menu pointing secondary vertical>
            <Menu.Item name='home' active={activeItem === 'home'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
            <Menu.Item name='messages' active={activeItem === 'messages'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
            <Menu.Item name='friends' active={activeItem === 'friends'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
          </Menu>
              </Sidebar>
              <Sidebar.Pusher>
                <Segment basic>
                  <Header as='h3'>Application Content</Header>
                  <Image src='/assets/images/wireframe/paragraph.png' />
                </Segment>
              </Sidebar.Pusher>
            </Sidebar.Pushable>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

My another layout which contain button for same link:

```
<Button content='message' onClick={() => {this.setState({activeItem:'message})}}/>
```

I am new to react.How can i set menu item message active on button click as well.??

Answer (score 1):

Add new prop `activeItem` to `SidebarLeftOverlay` class:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class SidebarLeftOverlay extends Component {

  state = { visible: false, activeItem: 'home' }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const updateActiveItem = nextProps.activeItem && nextProps.activeItem !== this.state.activeItem

    if (updateActiveItem) {
      this.setState({ activeItem: nextProps.activeItem })
    }
  }

...
} // end of class

SidebarLeftOverlay.propTypes = {
  activeItem: PropTypes.string
}
```

Then, provide props to the class component:

```
<SidebarLeftOverlay activeItem={this.state.activeItem} />
```

So when you click at the button your state `activeItem` changes, and `SidebarLeftOverlay` will re-render according to new state

Comment: can you please paste your jsx code here, i am not getting which function to call in SidebarLeftOverlay Component JSX

Comment: The full JSX code for that component is described in the question. To make it work just copy and edit the component  with my provided changes